# How do I counter a zergling rush?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've been confronted to a lot of zerg players only playing zergling rush and it's pretty annoying. I usually play terran and I have a lot off difficulties countering these.

The best thing I found was [this build](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gj1GPmNmiJI) which helped me countering the rush and the next wave until I had enough units to attack and beat him.

What is the best build against a Zerg, keeping the zergling rush in mind ? (feel free to post protoss solution too. The best zerg solution is ... wait for it ... zerglings !)

Comment: IMHO the Build in the video works quite well against rush but leaves you in a bad economical situation if the enemy doesn't rush (and i think that higher leagues rush less than the lower leagues).

Comment: @dbemerlin: Seriously, what league are you playing in? I feel like you have an opposite opinion on everything that is proven to not work. I cannot stress enough how behind you would be if you decided to go Planetary fortress as opposed to Orbital Command. Not to mention, you will be wasting all your resources on that defense instead of building your Baracks for units and to further develop your tech tree. If you built any buildings too far away from your P. Fort. then you would risk getting harrassed by the Zerg. He could even just run in a bunch of Zerglings and dominate your workers.

Comment: @Doug: That is actually exactly what i said: If he does a 6 or 7-pool rush the planetary fortress defends you, _but_ you will be in a bad economical situation (not many resources, no barracks, etc). If he really did a 6/7-pool then he will be in a similar situation so you can win. If he did anything else than those 2 build orders then you are... well... dead. Edit to clarify: I would _never_, _ever_ build a planetary fortress in the beginning myself (actually i never built one yet) and i do not recommend it, _but_ if you _know_ he does 6-pool it might give an advantage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to turtle and block off your entrance. Do not use the strategy in that video. It is horrible.

As a Protoss Diamond player, I usually build my Gateway and Pylon in the entrance. I leave just enough space for a unit to pass by and I build a few Zealots to block off that narrow entrance. I also use stalkers to back up the Zealots and the Sentries to forcefield. From here, I turtle and tech up.

Terran players usually block off their entrance with supply depots (Supply depots can raise and lower for units to pass by) and a Barracks. Then they build a few marines first and then a bunker then they tech.

Remember to always scout too. Another tip is to be prepared for Mutalisks because Zerg players who mass Zerglings usually follow up with Mutalisks afterwards.

Comment: afaik a 6 or 7-pool build can attack faster than you can block the entrance _and_ get a defensive unit up, but i might be wrong, never played against one myself.

Comment: I've tried this and I'm a little too slow at it. I need an more efficient wall build order.

Comment: @dbemerlin Well, if you scouted the 6 pool (and you should scout at all times), then you can chrono boost a Zealot and put 1 probe in the narrow entrance until your Zealot comes out. If they do pass your defense then just use your probes to attack. 6 pool attacks will only have 6 Zerglings which is 3 larvae.

Comment: @Opera What is your build order? Are you building your 1st Supply depot at the entrance followed by a barracks at the entrance?

Comment: It worth noting that you shouldn't use a pylon as part of your wall unless you have to (which is sometimes the case) due to its lower hp, and an early break on the pylon can halt production.  Wall with 2 Gates, or Gate/Cyber (when possible) and always build 2 pylons to support your Gateways.

Comment: @Doug I often go 8 depot and 10 rax and I do wall-in :)

Comment: @Doug: It's not always possible to scout the enemy in time, i.e. you sometimes have to play on 4-player maps where, depending on your luck, you might have to scout 3 places and then it might be too late. I agree though that usually it should be possible to defeat the zerglings at least with your probes, though the zerglings will kill a lot of probes/scvs/drones if they don't get support from zealots/marines/your own zerglings fast.

Answer (score 3):

Something new players might now be aware of is how to stack scvs. Simply put, take all your scvs and send them to harvest a single mineral patch as the lings approach. When they are very close, attack them so they can all hit at the same time. Also, you might have a marine or 2 depending on the map size so put the marine in that stack as well.

Other strats :
1-Scout with the scv building your first supply depots, you will know where he rushes or not
2-Block your choke, nothing he can do then
3-Dont give up!

Many ling rushers are in fact, poor players so if their rush fails, they are both slowed by their cheap strat and in dire need of ideas about what to do next. So if you've lost a few scvs, nothing is lost, keep the choke blocked and pump scvs

Answer (score 1):

For Terran i think you first need to build a turtle, buildings strategically placed on the ramp to block the zerglings for a decent amount of time for you to build a small M&M army.

Word of caution you need to be accurate for this build to work, any hole in the turtle and it's gg.

Answer (score 0):

i build my supply depot behind the ramp. So the zergling can't go into my basis. you can put the space marines behind the depots. the space marines can attac the zerglings.

Answer (score 0):

For Terran I just wall in regardless of scouting. For any other race, you must scout early, but preferably just late enough to see the rush coming and respond. I main Terran and do some Zerg; if I Zerg rush and Protoss does not scout it it's GG.

Protoss can wall in if they must, the cost of 1 Pylon you will have to destroy is less than the cost of a Ling rush. If Zerg scouts your Ling rush, he responds with a Ling rush and pulling Drones or even building Roaches and microing the Drones to protect the Roaches, if he can get the Roaches out in time.

Essentially, if Zerg scouts your Ling rush you're dead. When I felt like Ling rushing, I try to deny the scout at all cost, so if your opponent is denying scouting at all cost, he's probably going Ling rush.